# Having trouble with classes derived from a List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, methods, subclass

I'm new to defining classes. I want to define a class dubbed 'dataplane' (as it's a 2-dimensional set of data used to store csv files, and therefore might be represented as a plane in space) that inherits all methods of the class `List<List<string>>` (if that is a class).

So far I've managed to declare the class and create a method to return a 'column' of data, but I can't invoke that method. I earlier had trouble with getting the class to inherit methods from the `List<List<string>>` class, but got there after some research.

For some reason when I try to translate tutorials to build a method returning the column of data in a `List<string>`, it doesn't let me invoke the method.

Could someone give me a clear example and Layman's terms explanation of how to  declare a class that inherits from another, and write a method for it that uses the class's value?

Alternatively, could someone describe how I could use extended methods for this?

Also, in case someone has insight, here's what I have so far:

```
public class dataplanematrix : List<List<string>>
{
    List<List<string>> dataplane;

    private List<string> getColumn (int value)
    {
            List<string> columnValue = new List<string>();
            foreach (List<string> line in dataplane)
            {
                columnValue.Add(line[value].ToString());
            }
            return columnValue;
    }
}
```

The above code's issue is that I can't call the getColumn method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you both inheriting from `List<List<string>>` and have a field with that type?

Comment: your method is private.

Comment: It's not directly related to your question, but I was wondering the same thing as was @MattiVirkkunen. I would suggest _not_ inheriting from `List<List<string>>` as it is consistent with the principle of preferring composition over inheritance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: @DanielPratt - It doesn't mean "avoid inheritance at all costs". In this case it is probably the right way to go. You get a lot of value for little code. But I think you're opening up a can of worms here starting this debate.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't know how citing a well-known and often cited principle of OOP is tantamount to starting a debate. Who was I debating before you replied to my comment? I also don't know who you're quoting as saying "avoid inheritance at all costs", but it wasn't me.

Comment: @DanielPratt - Sorry, I may have been a little strong in my language. I wasn't quoting, but trying to group the words together. I think you'll find in the article you linked to that there is far more inheritance there in the diagram to the right rather than composition. I think it means "use composition when the inheritance is anything more than just simple."

Comment: @Enigmativity Since we seem to be debating now, I disagree with your interpretation/translation of the principle cited. I also stand by my advice. Code tends to get more complex, not less so. Inheritance is often the path of least resistance only at first, which is the whole reason the principle I cited is a "thing" in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superficial problem is that you have declared your method `private` when it should be `public`.

However, your class definition is wrong. There's no need to have a field.

Just do this:

```
public class DataPlaneMatrix : List<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> GetColumn(int value)
    {
        List<string> columnValue = new List<string>();
        foreach (List<string> line in this)
        {
            columnValue.Add(line[value]);
        }
        return columnValue;
    }
}
```

There's also no need to do `line[value].ToString()` as `line[value]` will do just fine.

You could also define your class like so:

```
public class DataPlaneMatrix : List<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> GetColumn(int value)
    {
        return this.Select(line => line[value]).ToList();
    }
}
```

Or, if you're using C# 6.0, like this:

```
public class DataPlaneMatrix : List<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> GetColumn(int value) => this.Select(line => line[value]).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive. My issue there was not understanding that I would refer to the object under the class through 'this'.

Answer (score 2):

Make your method `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: Upvoting, @Valentin I hope you weren't the downvoter as this answer is older than your comment.

Comment: And if it's correct and nobody finds a good duplicate to link I'm going to vote to close at typo anyways :)

Comment: Note even if this method were made public, it would never return anything because `dataplane` never gets initialized to anything.  I feel there would need to be a lot added to this answer before it's truly helpful.

Comment: @Mike: I get the feeling he didn't post all of his code.

Comment: Cheers Matti. Didn't understand the nature of scope applied to methods.
If Mike meant that I didn't use the DataPlaneMatrix at any point, you were right and under my main class I am using it to store a small flat file database.